# How to remove an specific element by clicking on it in react js

Tags: reactjs

Here i have a mutiple customers and i want to reject the call of one of user , but here i don't know how to get the value of specific user to remove.. `rejectCall` function is removing all the customers while clciking the button ..Can anyone help me thanks in advance

```js
 const [names, setNames] = React.useState([]);

socket.on('start_call', async (customerName) =>{
  setNames(names => [...names, customerName]) 
  const localElement = document.querySelector('div#customerRequest');
  var acceptButton = document.createElement('input');
  acceptButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
  acceptButton.setAttribute("value", "Accept Video");
  acceptButton.onclick = initiateCall;
  var rejectButton = document.createElement('input');
  rejectButton.setAttribute("type", "button");
  rejectButton.setAttribute("value", "Reject Video");
  rejectButton.style.marginLeft ='20px'
  acceptButton.onclick = rejectCall;
  localElement.appendChild(acceptButton);
  localElement.appendChild(rejectButton);
})

async function rejectCall(){
  var element = document.getElementById('customerRequest')
  element.remove()
}


<div className="md-form" id="customerRequest">   
{ names.length > 0 && names.map((customer) => {  
  return (  
    <div style={{margin :5}}>
      <button value={customer} id="customer" onClick={initiateChat}>{customer}</button>    
    </div>)
    
})}
```

Here is the image for better understanding

[image]

Comment: This is not the react-way of doing this. You should not modify the DOM directly at all. We can probably give you some pointers, but I would recommend going through the react tutorial one more time. In this case you probably want to learn about `useState`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the `names` array index as the second argument to names.map, and then pass that index to your `initiateChat` or `rejectCall` method:

```
{ names.length > 0 && names.map((customer, index) => {  
  return (  
    <div style={{margin :5}}>
      <button value={customer} id="customer" onClick={()=> initiateChat(index)}>{customer}</button>    
    </div>)
    
})}
```

Inside of the `initiateChat` or `rejectCall` method, you can use the index to modify the `names` array, probably by using something like:

```
updatedNames = [...names].splice(index, 1);
setNames(updatedNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are manually building up these accept / reject buttons with vanilla JS, but you are using react - why not use all react?

```js
let [incomingCallers, setIncomingCallers] = React.useState([]);
socket.on('start_call', (customerName) => {
  setIncomingCallers([...incomingCallers, customerName]);
});

// This is rough, but follow me here

const rejectCall = (customer) => {
  //// reject call
  
}

const acceptCall = (customer) => {
  //// accept call
  
}
<div className="md-form" id="customerRequest">   
{ names.length > 0 && names.map((customer) => {  
  return (  
    <div style={{margin :5}}>
      <button value={customer} id="customer" onClick={initiateChat}>{customer}</button>    
      <div class={incomingCallers.includes(customer.name) ? 'show' : 'hide'}>
         <button  onClick={() => acceptCall(customer)}>Accept</button><button onClick={() => rejectCall(customer)}>Reject</button>
      </div>
    </div>)
    
})}
```

I started the same way with React (manually building things with vanilla JS). But I quickly learned: If I'm building views with Vanilla JS in React, I should re-evaluate what it is I'm trying to do. Because it is probably much easier to do. Only in rare cases should I need to use vanilla JS (I've never found a case for this, yet).